# Grails 3 'grails' vs 'gradlew' tasks

Tags: gradle, grails-3.0

I am experimenting with Grails 3, which is entirely Gradle based. To create an app, I run:

```
grails create-app myapp
```

Then to integrate it with Eclipse, I run:

```
gradlew eclipse
```

Then to create a new controller, I run:

```
grails create-controller org.me.myapp.test
```

Then to run some custom Gradle task, I run:

```
gradlew mytask
```

I guess I'm confused about which tasks I run via `grails` vs. which ones I run via `gradlew`. No documentation appears to exist on the matter - any ideas?

Comment: Really, **no one** from the Grails community is supporting Grails 3 yet? Bueller...

Answer (score 2):

A grails app does not exists until you run

```
grails create-app MyApp
```

After that, gradle is available via the wrapper. Just cd into the MyApp directory and ask the generated gradle wrapper it what it can do:

```
./gradlew tasks
```

Wow! That's a lot of stuff...

For more info check out: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#gradleBuild

But ... In the beginning, all grails commands were intended to be available via the gradle wrapper, but the dev team found some hinky things late in 3.0 development and had to shelve that idea ... So as of 3.0.9, all code-gen tasks are still done through the plain old, familiar grails command. Need a crazy.Person? Just use:

```
grails create-domain crazy.Person
```

But if you want to run your crazy.Person unit tests, you use:

```
./gradlew test --tests *Person*
```

Or test 'em all:

```
./gradlew test
```

Clear as mud? *spoiler* Changes in Grails 3.1 may make the interaction less schizophrenic.